# How to change multiple comboboxes with little code

Tags: vba, combobox

Here's my problem.

I have a userform with 10 comboBoxes. 
Instead of Select Case al those comboboxes one by one is
there a smart way to change **multiple** combobox properties such as backcolor or fontcolor?

So for example:

```
Sub ChangeMultipleComboBoxes()
Dim comboB as control

For Each comboB In Me.Controls
If TypeName(comboB) = "ComboBox" Then
comboB.BackColor = vbRed
End If
Next comboB

End Sub
```

The problem is that for comboB I can't seem to find any properties for changing it's backcolor or whatsoever.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried running that code, and if so what error did you receive?  Just because the property does not display in the list when accessing generic controls does not mean it's not there.  Try using `nameOfComboBox.` to view a list of accessible properties.  Running the code you provided correctly change the background of comboboxes for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zaider says, your code works. You just don't get the IntelliSense for the `ComboBox`-specific properties when it's declared as a `Control`, even though you can use the properties as you've done in your code. (Note that properties common to all controls, e.g., `Caption` are available.)

To get the Intellisense for all `ComboBox` properties, re-declare the `Control` as a `ComboBox` once you've determined that's what it is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim comboB As MSForms.ComboBox

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
        're-declare it as a ComboBox
        Set comboB = ctl
            'Now you get IntelliSens
            comboB.BackColor = vbRed
        End If
    Next ctl
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Lol I didnt checked my code that well than have I :p.
I hate the Intellisens that the VBA editor uses in excel. I'd rather have the one Xcode uses for objective-c. 
BUt thanks again, this saves me a lot of script space. 
Greetings Pidaji,